# Mathematica Nested Anonymous Variable Arity Functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, anonymous-function, arity

I'm trying to translate the following scheme code into Mathematica (version 8, if that matters):

```
(define (((lift g) . fs) . args)
  (apply g
         (map (lambda (f) (apply f args))
              fs)))
```

Then, you can do things like:

```
(let ((add (lift +))
      (square (lift sqr)))
  ((add (square sin) (square cos)) 42))
; returns 1, since sin^2(42) + cos^2(42) = 1
```

The part `(add (square sin) (square cos))` creates a function `x -> sin^2(x) + cos^2(x)`.

Anyway, I tried coding this in Mathematica, but I can't seem to get very far. Here's what I want to write:

```
lift[g_] := Function[{fs__}, Function[{args__},
            g @@ Map[(# @@ args)&, fs]]]
```

I want `fs__` and `args__` to be bound to the list of all arguments to their respective functions. But then Mathematica complains that the "parameter specification" for `Function` should be "a symbol or a list of symbols". I know that I can use the `()&` style anonymous functions and use `##` to get all arguments, but the problem is that when I nest two of these anonymous functions, I lose the ability to access the outer arguments from within the inner function.

How can I write anonymous functions with variable arity (and named arguments)? Or should I solve this problem another way in Mathematica?

Comment: Couldn't you just put the `##` sequence from the outer function in a constant using `With`? Then you could access it in the inner function, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this function does what you want, but you can capture the `SlotSequence` (##) of the outer function using `With`

```
lift[g_] := Function[
  With[{fs = ##},
   Function[
    With[{args = ##},
     g @@ Map[(#[args]) &, List[fs]]]]]]
```

Then:

```
lift[f][a, b][c, d]
```

-> f[a[c, d], b[c, d]]

Or, more readable:

```
lift[g_] := Function[
  With[{fs = g[##]},
   Through[fs[##]] &]]
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was looking for! Also, didn't know about the `Through` function, thanks!

Comment: @nikie Thank you for your answer on my image processing question, I upvote you here, as others force out that question from SO.

Answer (score 2):

nikie gave a great answer.  I hope this one complements it.

You can create temporary functions using `Module`, which gives you the full set of pattern options for the parameter specification.  For example, using nikie's concise method:

```
lift1[g_] := Module[{fn}, fn[a__] := Through[g[a][##]] &; fn]

lift1[f][a, b][c, d]
```

> ```
> f[a[c, d], b[c, d]]
> ```

In this particular case you could also use a `SubValues` rule like this:

```
lift2[g_][h__] := Through[g[h][##]] &

lift2[f][a, b][c, d]
```

> ```
> f[a[c, d], b[c, d]]
> ```

Or even without `Function` at all:

```
lift3[g_][h__][i__] := Through[ g[h][i] ]

lift3[f][a, b][c, d]
```

> ```
> f[a[c, d], b[c, d]]
> ```